# InvalidOperationException with MediaLibrary pictures

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, invalidoperationexception

I have a windows phone app and get sometimes InvalidOperationExceptions but not sure why and how to avoid them.
The problem function from the error report is `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibraryEnumerator_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].get_Item` and i get this stacktrace

```
"Frame    Image                             Function                                                                                                                                    Offset        
0        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibraryEnumerator_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].get_Item                                                 0x0003e4d8    
1        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibraryEnumerator_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].System.Collections.IEnumerator.get_Current               0x00000006    
2        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibraryEnumerator_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator_T_.get_Current    0x0000001c    
3        MapLense.ni.DLL                   MapLense.Helper.PictureMapping.Add                                                                                                          0x000000a8    
4        MapLense.ni.DLL                   MapLense.Helper.PictureMapping+_GetPicture_d__b.MoveNext                                                                                    0x000000f6    
5        mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess                                                                              0x00216c46    
6        mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification                                                         0x0000003a    
7        mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].GetResult                                                         0x0000001c    
8        MapLense.ni.DLL                   MapLense.Helper.Map+_AddPictureToMap_d__17.MoveNext                                                                                         0x00000118    
9        mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess                                                                              0x00216c46    
10       mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification                                                         0x0000003a    
11       mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].GetResult                                                         0x0000001c    
12       MapLense.ni.DLL                   MapLense.MainPage+_ViewModelOnPropertyChanged_d__1e.MoveNext                                                                                0x00000204    
13       mscorlib.ni.dll                   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore._ThrowAsync_b__0                                                                     0x00000036"
```

I also tried to add a try-catch block around the code block, but without a result

```
public static bool Add(DBPicture dbpicture)
{
    if (Pictures.ContainsKey(dbpicture.UniqueID))
        return true;

    var root = new MediaLibrary().RootPictureAlbum;

    foreach (var album in root.Albums)
    {
        if (album.Name != AppResources.CameraRollAlbumName) continue;

        for (var i = 0; i < album.Pictures.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var picture = album.Pictures[i];
                if (picture.Name == dbpicture.UniqueID)
                {
                    Pictures.Add(picture.Name, picture);
                    DBPictures.Add(picture.Name, dbpicture);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
#if DEBUG
                Logger.WriteLine("PictureMapping.Add(DBPicture)");
                Logger.WriteLine(e);
#endif
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I'm having the same issue with songs in the library. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it on my device or any emulator. I just know it from many error reports. It seems to be a problem only occuring in WP8 ("PhoneVersion `Mango`").

Comment: Can you determine on which picture it occurs, e.g. using a debugger?

Comment: Oh, and try to determine the InnerException by running in debug mode, stop when the error occurs and inspect the exception.

Comment: I know this exception also from the error reports.. earlier I hat this issue also on my device, so i transformed the foreach Loops to simple for Loops and add an error handler. This helped on my device, but since the error reports don't show a difference, I'm a little bit helpless..

Comment: Did you find the issue after all?

Answer (score 1):

Not really one answer but if the error is one the first `foreach` and the `try` is on the second it's not catching the exception put the `try` outside the

```
try
{
    var root = new MediaLibrary().RootPictureAlbum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Same crash for a small number of users. It's a very interesting problem and I believe it is with WP8 and not with your code. Finally I managed to repro it on a device but only occures if the debugger is detached. Two things you need to make sure.

1. `album.pictures` is not null
2. Instead if enumerating the `album.Pictures` try something like `album.Pictures.OrderBy(x=>x.Date);`

I know it looks strange but this workaround works.

Comment: Thanks - i give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exception today in my WP 8.0 app.
The user gets several thumbnail images of his "Camera Roll" media library in a custom control. When he selects one of these thumbnail i try to get the real image via "GetImage()".
The thumbnails worked fine, but GetImage() threw the exception. 
Apparently (that's my guess) some of the picture were corrupt or damaged. It never worked with them but other pictures had no problems.

So keep in mind that it might also be a damaged or corrupt file.